# How to add new values in dataset using R

Tags: r, dataset

I am new at R i want to know is i possible to make a new column Ripe fruit that would compare values from column firmness1 and add "Yes" if the value is higer than 2 and "No" if the value is lower than 2

[Exaple od dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWIFd.png)

Comment: See here for an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39634761/r-ifelse-statement

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: `df$Ripe_fruit <- ifelse(df$firmness > 2, 'Yes', 'No')`

Comment: Than you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try and work with the `ifelse()` here. It should look something like this:

```r
df$ripe <- ifelse(df$firmness1 == 1, "Yes", "No")
```

What this does is: 
1. It will look through you Dataframe and check whether the value is one. 
2. If it is equal to one than set a "Yes". 
3. If it isn't it will set a "No"